# Calling Form.Show() in series

Tags: c#

everyone.
How do I call a number of forms one after another (meaning call new form after previous one is closed). 
I wrote something like this;

```
Form1.Show();
Form2.Show();
```

and it naturally results in opening both forms simultaneously. How to make function to wait for the fist form to be closed?

Comment: Have you tried `Form1.ShowDialog()` ?

Comment: How is your form closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open one form, handle the [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event, and open the second form from within that.  Note that this is only necessary because your forms are not modal.  If you were using `ShowDialog()` the call would not return until the first form was closed and your code would work as it is currently structured.

If you require non-modal behavior (i.e., your user must be able to interact with the owner form while the owned form is open) then use something like this:

```
// very simplistic example...
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.FormClosed += delegate { new Form2().Show(); }
frm.Show();
```

Comment: @Farrel: No problem.  Do you understand the event handler assignment syntax and how that all works?  If not let me know.